# leaflet onClick add/remove circles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).
I have a number of circles, and I want to imply a global event listener [link](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#domevent) for those circles which will add some other circles in one click to any circle, and remove those added circles by the second click.
How is that possible?
[image: grapical description]

```
//the circles which will have an event listener
var circle1 = L.circle([44.6663888888889, 6.775],{radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#ff9900',fillOpacity:1});
var circle2 = L.circle([44.6502777777778, 6.79333333333333], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1});
...




//create an onClick event targeting circle 1 and 2 to add/remove circle3 and circle4
map.on('click', function(e){...?...});



var circle3 = L.circle([44.6191666666667, 6.81222222222222], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1});
var circle4 = L.circle([44.6761111111111, 6.795], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1});
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use map.on() it handles events of map container.

You need to group your circles with L.featureGroup():

```
// group circles like the ones to be clicked and ones to be shown
var group1 = L.featureGroup();
var group2 = L.featureGroup();
// circles to be clicked
var circle1 = L.circle([44.6663888888889, 6.775],{radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#ff9900',fillOpacity:1}).addTo(group1);
var circle2 = L.circle([44.6502777777778, 6.79333333333333], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1}).addTo(group1);
// circles to be shown with event
var circle3 = L.circle([44.6191666666667, 6.81222222222222], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1}).addTo(group2);
var circle4 = L.circle([44.6761111111111, 6.795], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1}).addTo(group2);
map.addLayer(group1);
// handle event of the group you choosed to be clicked
group1.on('click', function(){
      // check if second group is on the map
      if(map.hasLayer(group2)){
        map.removeLayer(group2);
      }
      else {
        map.addLayer(group2);
      }
    })
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u09g2mf/2/)